# MVC App throwing this error for ALL datetimes: error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'object'

Tags: c#, datetime, variables, model-view-controller

Ive got an MVC application that is showing this error for every datetime, no matter where that is in the application.

Example below:

[image]

The code still runs and gets past the line but the "startDate" variable still has the below error against it.

[image]

It doesn't matter if I use DateTime.date or .now or just set it to a specific date. It will always have that error. I can still do stuff with that variable later on in the code..

I feel theres some underlying issue somewhere but not sure what the next steps would be to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: @Llama - its been happening for months, restarting pc and visual studio, doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now is never used in you code. And I am suspecting date.Value is not a DateTime type.  Why you didn' try more efficent code

```
DateTime startDate;
if (isAmend) startDate=....
```

and tell us what error do you have after this?

Comment: thanks, that piece of code was just an example, if i do the same as you've done in that snippet it still has the error. Anywhere DateTime is used in my code it has the error, however it still works, it doesnt throw any exceptions of any kind. I'm beginning to suspect its not a code issue but an environment one with visual studio